# Add in-app purchase with parse.com

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, parse-platform, icarousel

I am developing cards app using parse.com as backend, the app is working perfect for free cards and i can display all cards and click on any card to have full view so customer can write the text and customise and send to friend.

My question is how to add premium cards to the app so customer needs to purchase first before he can use it and send to friends. is it possible to display both free and premium cards in the same view and add label with the price on premium cards?

I am using Carousol to display all cards and this the code for display cards

```
- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    self.cardFileArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


    //create new view if no view is available for recycling

       view = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 250.0f, 350.0f)] autorelease];


       PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:WALL_OBJECT3];

        query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheOnly;



        [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {

                cardFileArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:objects];
                PFObject *object = [cardFileArray objectAtIndex:index];
                PFFile *file = [object objectForKey:KEY_IMAGE4];

                [file getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                    if (!error) {

                        ((UIImageView *)view).image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];


                    }
                }];
            }
        }];



    }
```

And this the code when customer select the card to preview and edit

```
-(void)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel didSelectItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index{


    PFObject *object = [cardFileArray objectAtIndex:index];
    PFFile *file = [object objectForKey:KEY_IMAGE5];
    NSString *tmpObject = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",object.objectId];

     [HUD showUIBlockingIndicatorWithText:@"Loading Card"];

    [file getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {


            CardDetailsViewController*ptvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"cardsDetail"];

            [self.navigationController pushViewController:ptvc animated:YES];

            ptvc.ImageForDetail = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

            ptvc.imageString = tmpObject;
            ptvc.title = title2;

            [HUD hideUIBlockingIndicator];

        }
    }];

}
```

Can you help me how to add in-app purchase to my app

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You need to save the type of card (free/premium) or simply it's price in the code in the data you fetch from the query. Then, based on it's state, you can apply a label on the image in the -viewForItemAtIndex method.

As for implementing in-app purchase, you should read up on it [here](https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/).

Comment: Thanks, so shall I add price key in Parse query and add condition if price key is > 0 then go for app purchase and apply it. is it right?